# How to make NGINX proxy a request to the same process that requested it, without resolving the process unaccessible destination IP?

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, chromium

I'm facing a challenge while configuring Nginx as a proxy for a Dockerized service, which I couldn't find an answer for.

The destination runs in the dockerized server, and it is a Chromium browser instance. I can control the requests this browser makes through Javascript, and I want to strip Origin header to make a proper request to its own "localhost:PORT". So, I can request the browser's localhost and can perform requests to itself, but when I send the request outwards to Nginx to modify the headers, it can't find its way back.

Here is the Nginx configuration I'm using:

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name foo.foo; # my machine      
    location / { 
         proxy_pass http://$host;           
         # Headers I want to modify 
         proxy_set_header Origin ""; 
         proxy_set_header Host $host; 
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
     } 
}
```

I want to proxy back to the same process that firstly requested the Nginx, but without resolving the final IP. Now, it is trying to resolve the `$host` in my machine, which will be my localhost. I tried to use all sorts of configurations with no luck.

To sum up, I tried setting up Nginx in order to proxy to the destination localhost, but instead it always resolves `$host` to my machine's localhost.

How to make Nginx (or any kind of proxy) send the request back to the same process that requested Nginx without resolving its IP, if this is ever possible?